# compilation error with ternary operator

Tags: java, operator-keyword, ternary

I tried the following with ternary operator and I do not understand why it is not compiling. The issue seems so small but I do not understand and hence bothers me -

**Line 1** --> int a = false ? y+=1 : (x*=10);

**Line 2** --> int b = false ? y+=1 : x*=10;

**Line 1** compiles however **Line 2** does not. Why ?

How is the parenthesis making a difference in case of 3rd operand and not the second operand. I didn't have to use parenthesis with anything else in the 2nd / 3rd operands (Unary, string, basic arithmetic ...) Why just assignment operator and that too specifically 3rd operand ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the `()` around `x*=10`, the entire left-hand operand of the `*=` operator is `false ? y+=1 : x`, as though you had:

```
int b = (false ? y+=1 : x)*=10;
```

And as `false ? y+=1 : x` isn't a variable, it can't be the left-hand operand of `*=`.

The assignment operators (including compound assignment, `*=` and such) are very, very low in the [precedence list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), below the conditional operator (`? :`):

> **Operators Precedence**
>
> - postfix: `expr++ expr--`
> - unary: `++expr --expr +expr -expr ~ !`
> - multiplicative: `* / %`
> - additive: `+ -`
> - shift: `<< >> >>>`
> - relational: `< > <= >= instanceof`
> - equality: `== !=`
> - bitwise: AND `&`
> - bitwise: exclusive OR `^`
> - bitwise: inclusive OR `|`
> - logical: AND `&&`
> - logical: OR `||`
> - ternary: `? :`
> - assignment: `= += -= *= /= %= &= ^= |= <<= >>= >>>=`